# Change a field when select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table test as following :
test1

```
Name  NumbreMission 
John   1
John   2
John   3
Jack   1
Jack   2
Jack   3
Jack   4
Jack   5
```

I am looking to get the following result : select max(NumbreMission )

```
Name  NumbreMission 
John   
John   
John   3
Jack   
Jack   
Jack   
Jack   
Jack   5
```

Any idea? 
Any help would be the most appreciated ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.  Do you really want blank rows returned?  Or just the Name and the Max value?

Comment: @JiggsJedi Indeed , I want blank rows . but I didn't have an idea how can I do it ?

Comment: Mureinik has given you the answer you seek.

Comment: @JiggsJedi Did you test it? It produces an incorrect result. Andrews answer however is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CTE to get the max for each name, and then join that to the original table:

```
with CTE as
    (select
    name,
    max(numbremission) as maxnum
    from
    test1
    group by name)

select
    t1.name,
    cte.maxnum
from
    test1 t1
left outer join cte
    on t1.name = cte.name
    and t1.numbremission = cte.maxnum
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd635/3)

Answer (score 2):

The `rank()` function should do the trick, with a bit of jimmy-rigging:

```
SELECT Name, 
       CASE WHEN rk = 1
            THEN NumberMission 
            ELSE NULL 
            END AS NumberMission
FROM   (SELECT Name, 
               NumberMisson, 
               RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY NumberMission DESC) AS rk
        FROM   test1) t
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  I don't think this will do what the OP is asking

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce the desired output: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26f40/1 and also there's a typo `NumberMisson` in the inner select